# What is the best window size (in seconds) and hop size (in seconds) for a audio sample which has 3 second length?

Tags: voice-recognition, feature-extraction

I have some voice samples with 3s length size for an audio feature extraction project. First I select 0.5s window size and 0.2 hop size but I doubt how to select best window size and hop size for better results.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, these are hyper-parameters that need to be optimized on your data.

I often obtain decent results from a hop_length between 10 ms - 40 ms and a window length between 10 ms - 100 ms, depending on whether you want more frequency- or time- resolution.